# Active_scaffold record created message : Created #&lt;Docket:0x0000013800ec4df0&gt;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, activescaffold

I'm using Rails 6.1.7 and active_scaffold latest version with a very basic tutorial  one model app, I get this message on the form top when a record is created:

Created #<Docket:0x0000013800ec4df0>

Otherwise the app works fine.  Is this an active_scaffold artifact ?

D.

I cannot figure out where to look since  active_scaffold code handles the CRUD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

active_scaffold has a `to_label` method that tries to guess the name of the object.
https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/blob/48316f99957ad7191bb8a2faa2912ddf6c194694/lib/active_scaffold/extensions/to_label.rb

Judging by the implementation, one way of overriding this would be to add either `name`, `label` or `title` to the `Docket` class. Example:

```rb
class Docket < ApplicationRecord
  def label
    "docket #{id}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for a speedy response. The  quest for knowledge goes on .   :)

Comment: Great, please flag it as answered